# Calculating distance between polylines from same feature class using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, arcgis-10.5, feature-class

I have a feature class with multiple lines outlining the extent of a glacier through time. I would like to calculate the distance between consecutive years (i.e two polylines from the same feature class).

Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Is each line a closed one?